# Docker Compose - getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I am having a mysql connection problem when trying to access my PHP container (Which is making a connection to MariaDB container)

> mysqli_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name
>   or service not known in **/var/www/html/config.php** on line
>   **16**

It looks like the PHP container is not aware of my MariaDB container. How ever the configuration seems good. If I expose my db container, I am able to connect to it locally.

docker-compose.yaml

```
version: "3"
networks:
  api_server:
services:
  db:
    image: mariadb
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./mariadb_data:/var/lib/mysql
      - ./database_dump/dump.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/dump.sql
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
      MYSQL_USER: user
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: pass
      MYSQL_DATABASE: somedb
  php-server:
    image: php.core.image
    networks:
      - api_server
    build:
      context: ./php
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    depends_on:
      - db
    environment:
      ENV_NAME: dev
    ports:
      - 80:80
```

Dockerfile for PHP

```
FROM php:7.2-apache
RUN docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) mysqli

COPY . /var/www/html/
```

And my connection in php looks like:

```
define('DB_SERVER', 'db');
define('DB_USERNAME', 'user');
define('DB_PASSWORD', 'pass');
define('DB_DATABASE', 'somedb');

$db = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER,DB_USERNAME,DB_PASSWORD,DB_DATABASE);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`php-server` service is in `api_server` network, while `db` is in default network.

You need to add `db` to same network as `php-server` - either to `api_server` network or add another network and add both services to it.

Comment: Simpler still, delete all of the manual `networks:` configuration and let both containers be on the `default` network that Compose [sets up for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/).